# Workaround for ssh2_connect on Shared Hosting

Tags: php, ssh

I am trying to connect to make SSH connections with PHP my hosting company says we dont allow SSH connections on shared server.. so is there any workaround, some other functions that i can use to connect.

```
 <?php


    if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
    // log in at server1.example.com on port 22
    if(!($con = ssh2_connect("server5500.asd.com", 22))){
        echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
    } else {
        // try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
        if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "asd", "gh45@asd")) {
            echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
        } else {
            // allright, we're in!
            echo "okay: logged in...\n";

            // execute a command
            if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "ls -al" ))) {
                echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
            } else {
                // collect returning data from command
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $data = "";
                while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                    $data .= $buf;
                }
                fclose($stream);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: and what do you want to do with that connection?

Comment: It might be possible to popen('ssh...') but if 'we dont allow SSH connections' then maybe the post and / or DNS lookups are disabled?

Comment: "We do not allow SSH connections", for any serious ISP, means that outgoing connections to port 22/tcp are **blocked by a firewall**, *whatever function* you may use. You could perhaps circumvent this by opening a SSH port on, say, port 443/tcp on the target host. If you can. And in most countries this trick might be reason enough to terminate your account with prejudice; so the real answer would be, "change ISP, or try offering them more money".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net).  eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2("server5500.asd.com");
if (!$ssh->login("asd", "gh45@asd")) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```